# Compare URL in Angular using $location.path()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am trying to make certain sections open (i.e. 'call.html' not to perform authentication) for my single page app in angular.js using login service.

I would like to know how can I get path(http://www.example.com/app/#/call/1234) so I can compare it and redirect to 'login' page if the page is not 'call.html' ?

I have got the following code in my app.js  which seems to work but doesn't work in Chrome and I get following error:

```
TypeError: $location.path(...).contains is not a function
```

my **app.js**.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
    function ($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http)
    {
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser)
        {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current)
        {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in
            if($location.path().contains('call'))
            {
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                if ($location.path() !== '/login'  && !$rootScope.globals.currentUser && $location.path() !=='/')
                {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Any help of how to address this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend using ngRoute https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute or ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 8, accepted):

contains is a jquery method not of angularjs. So, using this line of code:

```
if($location.path().contains('call')){
```

will obviously throws an error, "contains is not a function".

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if($location.path().indexOf('call') > -1){
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$locationProvider` uses hashbangs by default (as evident from your path `/app/#/call/1234`) so if you don't set `html5Mode` to `true`, you will get an empty string if you try to fetch the URL path.

Try setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` and you should be able to get the URL path.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :-

```
var url = $location.url();
if(url.indexOf('call') > -1){
   console.log("Call present");
}
```